# Is it valid to copy data from one dataset to another if their distribution is the same?

Tags: probability-distributions, data-analysis

**Premise 1:** We measure how many people enter an ice cream store at any given hour during the day, for the entire year. The graph will look like a very long zig-zag pattern of 8760 hours/ticks.

**Premise 2:** We measure the same thing for a fast food restaurant. So we have 2 arrays/sets of amount of people entering the respective building at every given hour during the year.

**Premise 3:** Now we plot the ***distribution***(graph of "*How many times do X number of people enter the building at any given hour during the year?*") of each, and find that they are nearly identical in kurtosis and skewness. (height, width and position)

**Premise 4:** One day, we lose the measurements/data of March from the ice cream store.

**Question:**  Can we copy the measurements of March from the fast food restaurant to fill in the missing space of the ice cream's March-section? Would this be mathematically valid/justified? Can we safely assume that the March will be "close enough" of an imitation of the original so that we can work with the data?

Comment: Even if the distributions were identical (and not just similar) , the concrete data would still be random numbers, so we cannot do this. However, the knowledge that the distributions are very similar justifies to assume that the number of guests within a sufficient long period , say a month , will roughly coincide.

Comment: Ah, I see. So we can assume it for a month but not for a week nor day for example? If we were to add that we tolerate a 17-20% difference (e.g. 23/03/2022 12:00 ice cream store had 50 customers, but fast food restaurant had 60 that same hour, and we say "this is acceptable to let the 60 act as the 50"), then we can copy March from one to the other? Is there a way to know where the limit goes, how long the period must be to ensure coincidence?

Comment: This is very hard to generalize since the fluctuations depend on the concrete (assumed) distributions. It is clear that the chance that the numbers level out increases with the length of the period. The month was only a guess, maybe a week is enough as well (if the distributions are really close)